# Yii2 Standalone file Upload

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I'm trying to upload a profile picture without ActiveForm or Model.

According to Yii2 docs we can use [AdHoc Validation Rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation), In this example it's using email validation but i need file validation.

What i've tried:

```
public function actionPicture() {

    /* @var $user \app\models\User */
    /* @var $validator \yii\validators\FileValidator */

    $validator = new FileValidator(['extensions' => ['png','jpg']]); // Setting Allowed Extensions

    $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('avatar'); // Get File Object byName

    if( $validator->validate($file, $errors) ) { // Validate here
        $user = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()]);
        $user->avatar = 'profile-'.$user->id.'.'.$file->getExtension();
        if($user->save(false)) {
            $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@upload_dir').'/'.$user->avatar);
            Yii::$app->user->setIdentity($user);
            yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Profile Picture updated successfully');
        }

    } else {
        yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger',$errors);
    }

    return $this->redirect(['index']);

}
```

My Question: In the above code is it the standard way to use FileValidator with out active forms.

**Note: I know we can use [Yii2 File Upload](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html), but it's using Model which is not i wanted**

Comment: But u use your User model when before saving your file, it just interesting to me why you don't use this model for validating your file.

Comment: that because i used static html as a form and only for profile picture i've to separate Senarios in model. does that make sense to you ?

Comment: Nope this way,u use  $validator->validateValue($file) and check $validator for errors, i think. Because validate() method not trigered. u must call FileValidator own method for not model related file

Comment: Btw this peice of code is working fine !

Comment: It means work for you yeah, am i right